# Metasploit - Where has JTR gone?

Tags: metasploit, john-the-ripper

I remember using jtr in metasploit. jtr_crack_fast is no longer available for me along with other jtr commands. Yes i can still get regular jtr stand alone or just git but still.

What happen to jtr in metasploit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### They were remade as part of a cleanup

On 2020-01-31 (so almost exactly one year ago at the time of writing this), Rapid7 released  [this article](https://blog.rapid7.com/2020/01/31/metasploit-wrap-up-50/), in which they explain the history of how `jtr_crack_fast` and similar modules came to be.

If you don't care for the article, and just want the synopsis: The modules were all renamed to `crack_` instead of `jtr_`. You can also change whether or not you wish to use JtR or Hashcat as the backend, so that the commands are backend-independent. These new and improved commands also have other nice features added, such as `show_command`, which allows you to show the command being executed in the backend. The article explains it in more detail.

This change has been in Metasploit since version 5.0.72.